# Styling code within php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, styles

I'm having trouble styling the information that I'm pulling from the database. If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it. I tried defining $style within the while loop, and then assigning it the $questions, but nothing happens on the webpage. I'm new with coding in general, and while I have some knowledge of css, I don't know how you use it within php script.

**style for the background I was trying to put behind each question***

```
#frm1
        {
            background: #D9D9D9;
            margin:auto;
            top:150px; left:200px; width:880px; height:60px;
            position:absolute;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
            font-size: 9px;
            font-style: italic;
            line-height: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding:10px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            border: inset 1px solid #333;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
         }
```

**PHP code retrieving info from database***

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 0)
    {
        $toggle = false;
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and $i<10 ) 
             {
                        $i++;
                        $toggle = !$toggle;
                        if($toggle)
                        $style = "id:frm1;";
                        else
                        $style = "background: white;";

                        questions .= "<a style='$style'> </a>";
                        questions .= "Titlee: " ."<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['title'] . "</a> <br> ";
                        questions .= "Details: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['detail'] . "</a> <br>  ";
                        questions .= "Category: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['categories'] . "</a> <br> <br> <br> ";
                    }
                    echo  questions;
                }
```

Comment: You should use classes instead; they'll provide cleaner code and more flexibility. Anyway, the problem here would appear to be that the link with the style is empty...

Comment: CSS classes would go a long way to simplifying this. As you have it here, you're practically using a `<font>` tag.

Comment: I tried using CSS classes, but I didn't know how to call them within the php.

Comment: style='id:frm1' is incorrect; you want id='frm1'

Comment: You should use class instead of id.ID should be unique on page.

Answer (score 1):

> while I have some knowledge of css, I don't know how you use it within
>   php script.

Okay.

Your PHP script is a PHP script on the server, and results in a regular HTML page for the user. [See the bottom of the answer, I'll try to give you a quick overview]

You can use CSS exactly as you would with a plain HTML page, and it will work just fine despite being backed by PHP.

This means **do not use style="$style"**. Style attributes are Bad.

As it looks like you want to construct your CSS conditionally, my suggestion is either:

- Change a class using PHP, and have an external stylesheet which acts on that class
- Put the styles you're conditionally changing inside `<style>` tags in your header, and change those with PHP.

**This answer will use the first option**
(Edited to take into account new information)

In your PHP code, before your links:

```
if($toggle) {
    $questions.='<div id="frm1">';
}
else {
    $questions.='<div id="frm2">';
}
```

In your PHP code, after your links:

```
 $questions .= "</div>";
```

And finally, in either your external stylesheet, or your in-head `<style>` tags:

```
#frm1 {
   ...
}
#frm2 {
   ...
}
```

**Quick overview of server-side languages**

So, web programming.  This is generally done in two ways. **client side** (read: javascript) and **server side** (in your case, read: php, but there's a lot more to this).

With a client side language like javascript, the code actually gets sent to the web browser. The web browser then modifies the contents of the page according to what the script says for it to do. This means your users can see the code, even turn it off in their web browser or execute other javascript in its place.

With a server side language, there's a different workflow.

1. The user asks for your webpage (identified by its URL)
2. The web server (read: your webhosting) receives this request, and looks up what the webpage is
3. Finding that the webpage is a php page, the **server** executes the php code
4. The php code gives the server an html page (which you have built, as you can see, your php script outputs HTML)
5. The server sends **the resulting html code** to the user

Note that the web browser, which is the component doing all of the processing of HTML and CSS, never sees the php. By the time your php script reaches your users, it's just an html page.

Because the web browser only sees an HTML page, there is no functional difference between using CSS on your php script, and using CSS on a regular HTML page.

Comment: I really appreciate your extensive answer. I updated my question a bit with the actual background I'm trying to use behind each question. I left it out before originally because I thought it would be easier to ask the question with just the color background. I understand that the css produces the same results in the php as it does in the html, but you seem to have to code it differently. If i was in html, I would do something like <div id=frm1> but the div tags don't seem to work in the php.

Comment: It will still work fine - <?php echo('<div id="frm1"> ... </div>'); ?>

Comment: i.e. do exactly what you would do in HTML, but change the ID (or remove it entirely, or whatever) conditionally using PHP as given in the simplified example above.  By the way, try viewing your HTML source in your webbrowser (Ctrl+U ?) to see if it looks correct -- if it's not coming out exactly how it would if you wrote a plain HTML page, then THAT is why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 0) {
    $toggle = false;
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and $i<10 ) {
        $i++;
        $toggle = !$toggle;
        if($toggle)
        $style = "background: #D9D9D9;"; else
        $style = "background: green;";

        questions .= "<a href='#' style='display:block;$style'> </a>";
        questions .= "Titlee: " ."<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['title'] . "</a> <br> ";
        questions .= "Details: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['detail'] . "</a> <br>  ";
        questions .= "Category: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['categories'] . "</a> <br> <br> <br> ";
    }
    echo  questions;
}
```

The problem was your a-tag doesn't have a href attribute and since it's displayed inline (default-behaviour) the background CSS property won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of style, build classes and define them in css.

```
if ($toggle)
     $questionClass="redBackground";
else
     $questionClass="greenBackground";
$questions.="<a class='$questionClass'>";
```

Also, definitely look into mysqli or pdo. mysql_ functions are deprecated and not nearly as cool!

Comment: What would switching to mysql or pdo do differently? I wish I did more research before I started learning how to interact with MYSQL, but at this point, i'm probably just going to stick with mysql until I'm familiar with HTML and PHP before I switch to MYSQLi or PDO. But I appreciate the advice.

Comment: It's not only a lot safer, but eventually your code will stop working as mysql_ functions are deprecated. (Meaning they still work for now, but in upcoming releases will be dropped entirely.) Also, if you want to do object-oriented PHP programming, which you almost certainly will at some point, you will definitely want to use objects for your database transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do -

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 0)
{
    $toggle = false;
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and $i<10 ) 
         {
                    $i++;
                    $toggle = !$toggle;
                    if($toggle)
                      $style = "bg";
                    else
                      $style = "bg_green";
                    echo("<a class='".$style."'> </a>");
                    echo("Titlee: " ."<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['title'] . "</a> <br> ");
                    echo("Details: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['detail'] . "</a> <br>  ");
                    echo("Category: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['categories'] . "</a> <br> <br> <br> ");


          }
```

In this file add -

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bg {
         background: #D9D9D9;
      }
      .bg_green {
         background: green;
      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate on your counter `$i` with `$i % 2` to switch between two CSS classes. This will give you `0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...` and so select the first and second CSS class name in turn.

PHP:

```
$css_class = array('frm1', 'second');
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and $i<10 )
{
    $i++;
    questions .= "<a class='$css_classes[$i % 2]'> </a>";
    questions .= "Titlee: " ."<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['title'] . "</a> <br> ";
    questions .= "Details: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['detail'] . "</a> <br>  ";
    questions .= "Category: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['categories'] . "</a> <br> <br> <br> ";
}
```

and in your CSS file you define the two classes

```
.frm1 {
    background: #D9D9D9;
    margin:auto;
    top:150px; left:200px; width:880px; height:60px;
    position:absolute;
    ...
}

.second {
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Okay I think I original laid out my question poorly, and I've updated it. I'm not trying to get an alternating background but rather the same background (#frm1) behind each question.

Comment: @user203837 You still switch between the two styles, so it's just different CSS styles. I updated my answer accordingly. If this is still not what you want, show a HTML example how it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

As ben said use class.

first create a class

```
<style>
.gray{background: #D9D9D9;}
.green{background: green;}
</style>
```

Then try this

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 0)
    {
        $toggle = false;
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and $i<10 ) 
             {
                        $i++;
                        $toggle = !$toggle;
                        $style = ($toggle)?"green":"gray";

                        $questions .= "<a class='".$style."'> Put some thing here </a>";
                        $questions .= "Titlee: " ."<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['title'] . "</a> <br> ";
                        $questions .= "Details: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['detail'] . "</a> <br>  ";
                        $questions .= "Category: " . "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $rows["question_id"] . "'>". $rows['categories'] . "</a> <br> <br> <br> ";
                    }
                    echo  $questions;
    }
```

Please try it, I have not tested but it should work, according to your need.

Comment: What this would appear to do is to just highlight whatever I put in the "Put some thing here" space in the first $questions.=... I might have had the code laid out poorly when asking my question, but what I was trying to do was to make a solid background behind the 3 lines (title, details, and category). I updated my code with the css of the background that I'm trying to put behind each whole question...